# More than one WIDs associated with "Chrome" and with "evince"?

Tags: chrome, xdotool

I am running Google Chrome browser with 17 tabs.

```
$ xdotool search --name "Google Chrome" 
79691777
```

1. Why does the following return 7 WIDs? 7 doesn't match any of the
   fact that I have 17 tabs in a Google chrome Window.

   ```
   $  xdotool search --name "Chrome"
   79691777
   69206017
   69206019
   69206054
   69206057
   69206065
   69206207
   ```
2. I want to find out what window are for the WIDs other than the first one. But why does it fail to activate the second  WID?

   ```
   $ xdotool windowactivate 69206017
   XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)
   ```

Similarlly for evince

```
$ xdotool search --class evince
161480705
161480711


$ xdotool windowactivate 161480705
XGetWindowProperty[_NET_WM_DESKTOP] failed (code=1)
```

Thanks.

Comment: I don't know why there is more than one window ID but I found a workaround. When searching use `--desktop 0` parameter like this: `xdotool search --desktop 0 --class "Google-chrome-stable"`. After that I get only one window ID or more if there is some kind of popup confirm windows etc. When there is more than one ID, first one seems to be the main window ID.